# $\{y \mid \limsup\limits_{i \rightarrow \infty}d(x_i,y) \leq 1\}$ is a borel set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can I write the set $\{y \mid \limsup\limits_{i \rightarrow \infty}d(x_i,y) \leq 1\}=\bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n \geq N}\{y \mid d(y,x_n) \leq 1\}$? I am trying to write the set as some combination of unions and intersections of open or closed sets in order to show the set is Borel. I tried to write the set as $\{y \mid \text{inf}\{\text{sup}\{d(y,x_k) \mid k \geq i\}\}\leq 1\}$ but am unsure whether this set is obviously closed. If $\limsup\limits_{i \rightarrow \infty}d(x_i,y) \leq 1$. Then there would be an integer $m$ such that $d(x_i,y) \leq 1$ or all $i \geq m$, so would the answer be $\bigcap\limits_{i=m}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=i}^{\infty}\{y \mid d(x_k,y) \leq 1\}$ ?

If none of my answers are correct, could someone help me try to show $\{y \mid \limsup\limits_{i \rightarrow \infty}d(x_i,y) \leq 1\}$ is a borel set?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path is this correct now?

Comment: No, not yet. You are missing the points for which $\limsup_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,y)=1$, but for which $d(x_n,y)>1$ holds frequently.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Is there any way to write the set on the left as something similar? I am trying to show the set is Borel. Would switching the inequality to strict help anything?

Comment: @Tasso you should disclose to the audience what you edited in your question after someone posts an answer. Nevertheless, your new formulation still doesn't work. Consider $x_n=1/n$ if $n$ is odd and $x_n=n$ if $n$ is even. Then $0$ belongs to the $\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n\geq N}\{y:d(x_n,y)\leq 1\}$ but $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(x_n,0)=+\infty$

Comment: @MatthewPilling i reverted it back to the original in order to make it more in line with the answer. Do you have a suggestion how to write the set as a union of open/closed sets in order to show it is Borel?Do I need to take a completely new approach?

Comment: @Tasso Just an FYI I am not ignoring you I just haven't figured out your problem yet!

Comment: @MatthewPilling I asked the question over again and this was the solution:$\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap\limits_{n=N}^\infty \{y: d(x_n, y)\leq 1+ 1/k\}$.

Comment: @Tasso thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $x_n = 2^{-n}$ and $y = -1$. Then $\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} d(y, x_n) = 1$. But there does not exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $d(y, x_n) \leq 1$. In fact, we see that for all $n$, $d(y, x_n) = 1 + 2^{-n} > 1$.